# Flutter/Dart DropdownMenu doesn't update when I call a setState and modify my Locale variable

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, localization

My problem is that my DropdownMenu values don't update when I change Locale and SetState.

`print(races.values.toList());` shows me the correct values after a SetState, so "races" variable is updated correctly.

```
flutter: [Elf, Dwarf, Gnome, Halfling, Human, Vran, Werebbubb, Witcher]
flutter: [Elf, Nain, Gnome, Hobbit, Humain, Vran, Marmotin, Sorceleur]
```

***Edited**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

class RacesToWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  const RacesToWidget(this.controller, {super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _RacesToWidgetState();
}

class _RacesToWidgetState extends State<RacesToWidget> {
  TextEditingController get controller => widget.controller;
  Map<String, String> races = {};

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    races = {
      'elf': AppLocalizations.of(context).elf,
      'dwarf': AppLocalizations.of(context).dwarf,
      'gnome': AppLocalizations.of(context).gnome,
      'halfling': AppLocalizations.of(context).halfling,
      'human': AppLocalizations.of(context).human,
      'vran': AppLocalizations.of(context).vran,
      'werebbubb': AppLocalizations.of(context).werebbubb,
      'witcher': AppLocalizations.of(context).witcher
    };
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(races.values.toList());
    return Column(children: [
      Center(
          child: DropdownMenu(
              initialSelection: races.values.toList().first,
              enableFilter: false,
              enableSearch: false,
              controller: controller,
              onSelected: (String? value) =>
                  setState(
                  () => controller.text = value ?? races.values.toList().first),
              dropdownMenuEntries: races.values
                  .toList()
                  .map<DropdownMenuEntry<String>>((String value) =>
                      DropdownMenuEntry<String>(value: value, label: value))
                  .toList()))
    ]);
  }
}
```

The only way to update the values in my DropdownMenu is to go back to the previous screen, and when you come back to this one, the values are updated.

I tried changing the place of the setState and placing it in the parent widget. But the result is the same.

Any ideas on what's causing my issue and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't see where you're calling setState, if at all.  I would think it would be within onSelected.  You should probably also move the initialization of races out of build and into didChangeDependencies so that it's not reconstructed on every repaint (could be expensive if animation).

Comment: Yes, in my code there is a setState in the onSelected. While testing the parent widget, I forgot to put it back. I've updated the code.
I didn't know about didChangeDependencies, so I've added it too. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems solved (thanks ChatGPT)
My dropdownMenu needed a UniqueKey() to update correctly.

Here's the correct code for those who need it:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Center(
          child: DropdownMenu(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              enableFilter: false,
              enableSearch: false,
              controller: controller,
              onSelected: (String? value) =>
                  setState(() => controller.text = value ?? races.values.first),
              dropdownMenuEntries: races.values
                  .map<DropdownMenuEntry<String>>((String value) =>
                      DropdownMenuEntry<String>(value: value, label: value))
                  .toList())),
      const Divider()
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try this?

```
onSelected: (String? value) {
    setState(() {
       controller.text = value ?? races.values.toList().first;
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, in my code there is a setState in the onSelected. While testing the parent widget, I forgot to put it back. I've updated the code.